# How can I get Homebrew and MAMP (Pro) to play nicely together?

Tags: macos, bash, ruby, homebrew, mamp

I am using MAMP Pro for most of my local application development and am trying to install ruby , etc via homebrew however homebrew will give me the following warning:

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
```

`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/bin/php-config
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/curl-config
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/freetype-config
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/libmcrypt-config
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/libpng-config
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/libpng15-config
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/sablot-config
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/xml2-config
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/xslt-config
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/yaz-config
```

How can I ensure that this works as it should and that there are no problems in the future when installing packages? Ay suggestions is welcomed.